# Doxygen ignores @method

Tags: php, documentation, doxygen

i have some magic methodes but to have still auto complete functions in netbeans.
I use above all classes a block like:

```
/**
 * @method int getEavConfigId() get object id
 * @method Model_DbTable_EavConfig setEntityType(string $entity_type) set entity_type possible values site, user, pc, ticket, alarm ; eav field is realted to this table
 * @method string getEntityType() get entity_type possible values site, user, pc, ticket, alarm ; eav field is realted to this table
 * @method Model_DbTable_EavConfig setCompanyId(integer $company_id) set company_id
 * @method integer getCompanyId() get company_id
 * @method Model_DbTable_EavConfig setType(string $type) set type possible values textfield, textarea, radio, checkbox, select ; eav field type
 * @method string getType() get type possible values textfield, textarea, radio, checkbox, select ; eav field type
 */
```

For netbeans this works pretty good.
But doxygen seams to ignore it totaly.

Has someone an idea if it is possible to let doxygen accept the @method tag?

I know that phpDocumentator can handle this. But i prever the documentations of doxygen, caused by several reasons.

Comment: *You can submit enhancement requests in [the bug tracker](http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/). Make sure the severity of the bug report is set to "enhancement".* ([via](http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/)) - and in case reading sources helps: https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen

Comment: @hakre thx, i open i new bug tracker issue. Hopfully it will not be ignored: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=706099

Comment: Nice report I'd say! Also the answer below doesn't look too bad.

Comment: see this link http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/faq.html

Answer (score 3):

Doxygen has already implemented your problem solution and it is known as ALIASES. The definition of an alias should be specified in the configuration file using the ALIASES configuration tag.

## Simple aliases

The simplest form of an alias is a simple substitution of the form

```
name=value
```

For example defining the following alias:

```
ALIASES += sideeffect="\par Side Effects:\n"
```

will allow you to put the command \sideeffect (or @sideeffect) in the documentation, which will result in a user-defined paragraph with heading Side Effects:.

**Note** that you can put \n's in the value part of an alias to insert newlines.

Also note that you can redefine existing special commands if you wish.

Some commands, such as \xrefitem are designed to be used in combination with aliases.

Hope this resolve your problem and for more info visit [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/custcmd.html)

Comment: thx for answer. But if i understood documentation right, alias can not handle what i am looking for. Because with aliases it seams not be posibble to have real defined methodes like:   `public function setXyz()`    and    virtual (magic) methodes like    `@method int getEavConfigId() get object id`     combined together in the "Public Member Functions" block.

Comment: Yes, it is successfully generating docs as I have given the attribute method to change as \fn in config file ALIASES = method="\fn"

Comment: Sorry but it wont work. Because \fn its self will also not work. I tried following example:  `/*! \fn string Model_DbTable_EavConfig::testTest(string c,int n) 
 *  \brief A member function.
 * 
 *  \param c a string.
 *  \param n an integer.
 *  \return a character pointer.
 */`

Comment: \fn is just for documentatint real function but not for `magic` function that not exist.

Comment: Have a look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call to understand what magic methodes are.

Comment: Having the same problem: I need to document functions which don't exist in the code but are generate by a schema using things like `__call()' Any solution found? @greenrover